# Convert struct_time to String in python has error

Tags: python-3.x, time, argparse, strptime, strftime

I run my.py `20180822` with code as below to convert struct_time to string

```
def mkdate(datestr):
    return time.strptime(datestr, '%Y%m%d')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Download Images from Web Site')
parser.add_argument('startDate',type=mkdate, nargs='*', help='Start Date to Download')

    if args.startDate:
        startDate = time.strftime('%Y%m%d', args.startDate)
```

I got error as below, what can I do though I googled without any answer...

```
    [time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=234, tm_isdst=-1)]
2018/08/23 16:21:28 ERROR    Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My.py", line 8, in main
    startDate = time.strftime('%Y%m%d', args.startDate)
TypeError: Tuple or struct_time argument required
```

Comment: I got what I need, it is

Answer (score 1):

I got what I need, it is

```
startDate = time.strftime('%Y%m%d', args.startDate[0])
```